# How to connect specific user to specific product

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I've product class that contain

```
 String id;
  String address;
  String image;
  bool isFavourite;
  String userEmail;
```

I've also google sign in method that in the end return this:

```
  FirebaseUser user = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
    print(user.displayName);
    return user;
```

How do i connect specific user to specific product?

For example in this method:

```
 final Map<String, dynamic> responseData = json.decode(response.body);
      final Product addedProduct = Product(
        id: responseData['name'],
        address: address,
        image: image,
        userEmail: userEmail //the problem
      );
```

I expect to get here 3 arguments, currently 2 hard coded and the user name should be dynamic based on which email login is currently use through the sign in method, but i can't get access to the user.displayName/email etc

```
  onPressed: () => model.addProduct('USA',
                  'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/01/27/22/31/girl-3959203__340.jpg',),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `email` property of `FirebaseUser`. Check [API docs](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseUser-class.html) or simply dive in to the source code on your IDE.

```
FirebaseUser _user;

void _signIn() async {
  _user = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
  print(_user.displayName);
}

void addProduct (String address, String image){
  final Map<String, dynamic> responseData = json.decode(response.body);
  final Product addedProduct = Product(
      id: responseData['name'],
      address: address,
      image: image,
      userEmail: _user.email //the problem
  );
}
```